# What are 'quasi implementations'?

Tags: c#, resharper

Sometimes when searching for references of a member, I get this popup, which often takes annoyingly long, so I tend to cancel. But I wonder: what am I missing? What are 'quasi implementations'?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer at resharper support](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206044949-Is-this-a-Find-Usage-bug-) quasi-implementation is when class implements the interface via derived method while the class containing the the implementation does not implement the interface. I.e. something like the following:

```cs
public interface IProvideFoos
{
    IFoo ProvideFoo( ) ;
}

public interface IFoo {}

public class BaseWhatever 
{
    public IFoo ProvideFoo( ) => throw new NotImplementedException( );
}

public class RealWhatever : BaseWhatever, IProvideFoos {}
```

Several issues at YouTrack for ReSharper call it the same - [One](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-284975/Usage-not-found-for-an-interface-implementation), [Two](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-46273), [Three](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-417302/Quasi-implemented-interface-member-is-highlighted-as-never-used)

Maybe useful also:

- [Why is a base class in C# allowed to implement an interface contract without inheriting from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944410/2501279)

Comment: Thanks! So `BaseWhatever.ProvideFoo()` would be the quasi-implementation. Got it!

Comment: @mike yes, exactly. Was glad to help!