# Base class implementing the interface that is in child class

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;


public interface MustImplement
{
    public void DoSomething();
}

public class Base
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something must be done");
    }
}

public class Child: Base, MustImplement
{
    //I don't have to implement the MustImplement interface here since the base class did it.
}
```

As you can see, the child class just make use of the `DoSomething()` implemented in the base class and the compiler treated this as valid.

I saw someone did something similar in their code, this is why I create a code snippet just to convey the idea.

Is there any reason why we should do thing this way instead of doing `public class Base: MustImplement` and implement `public virtual void DoSomething()` in the base class instead?

Comment: That is some form of duck typing, although it works, you will have fun when searching for types that implement this interface.

Comment: @aybe I never did this before. I just happened to saw the code written by someone with this structure. So I'm curious why is it done this way and whether there's any good in it.

Comment: This is not THE way to do it. Maybe it's advantageous in some specific situation but, as you haven't specified a particular scenario, we can't judge that. Just do things the proper way unless you have a specific reason for "breaking the rules".

Comment: @aybe I would argue that it is not duck-typing though, it would be duck-typing if you could use the `Base` as `IMustImplement`, but agree, looking for implementations could be "fun" (though Rider for example seems to find it).

Comment: "implement an interface" is just "must have these methods", it is not required that those methods are defined in *this* class - baseclass is also fine. However, this construction is strange

Comment: @GuruStron It *vaguely* looks like a  but isn't really in the end, hence *some form*!

Answer (score 6):

This is also sometimes called [quasi implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76663770/2501279) and I would argue that there are not much places where it is useful. One thing I could think of is when for some reason it is needed to have different inheritors some of which should not implement `IMustImplement` (though you can still "reabstract" with explicit interface implementation `void MustImplement.DoSomething() => base.DoSomething();`, or hiding one - `public new void DoSomething() => base.DoSomething();`).

Or `Base` is class coming from some package and `public class Base : IMustImplement` can't be done.

Note that finding such quasi-implementation could be a bit of headache, not sure that all IDEs fully support them, so if it is possible and there is no actual need in limiting/splitting inheritors into ones that implement and don't the interface - move it to the base class, I would argue it will make more readable and intuitive code.

Comment: In the context of the code I read, I saw the base class implemented all the method in the interface. So I guess there's no logical reason for them to code things that way.

Comment: @caramel1995 do all derived classes implement the interface? If yes - then I would argue there is not much point in not moving the interface to base class

Comment: Yes they are. I was flabbergasted when I read the code, I'm thinking is there some trick in C# that I do not know.

Comment: @caramel1995 you can consider it as some kind of trick preventing passing `Base` to method accepting the interface, is it useful is a whole another question =)))

Comment: @Gurut Stron but the base is an abtract class =)))

Comment: @caramel1995 not in the post;) And you can always have a reference to `Base`. But again, I personally don't see any point of such separation. Also there is a possibility that this was some refactoring when some tool has not worked completely  correct when moving some functionality to the base class.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to judge why would someone do this because the codes does not convey enough information behind its intent.

Honestly, based on your observation, sound like the Base already implements MustImplement. This conveys that perhaps it should be the base class that has the interface instead of the child.

```cs
public interface MustImplement
{
    public void DoSomething();
}

public class Base : MustImplement
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something must be done");
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, with SOLID principles like Liskov substitution the parent class and the child class are always interchangeable. So, moving the interface to the parent actually make more sense from this perspective. Because putting the interface on the child means the parent can no longer work as a substitute.

Comment: _"Liskov substitution the parent class and the child class are always interchangeable"_ - LSP defines only base -> child substitutability, not `child -> base`: _"Functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able to use objects of derived classes without knowing it."_